# Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: selenium

I am new to Selenium. Trying following code and it works for Firefox.
When I try for Safari, getting error.

```
package MyTestPkg;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class MyTestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          WebDriver driver =new SafariDriver();
          driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in");
          String i = driver.getCurrentUrl();
          System.out.println(i);
          driver.close();
         }
}
```

OSX 10.10.3
Selenium 2.46
Safari 8.0.6

### ERROR

```
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 43288
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler$1 operationComplete
INFO: Connection opened
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Driver connected in 1998 ms
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Closing connection
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping Safari
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
INFO: Stopping server
Jun 22, 2015 5:47:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'Lajeeshs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.224', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:42)
    at MyTestPkg.MyTestClass.main(MyTestClass.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.execute(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:578)
    ... 6 more
```

Any pointer how to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you please provide your drivers deatails along with safari version ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all:

```
Could not start a new session.
Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

In this case, unless you had a network glitch that didn't allow you to access the website, it is the latter - i checked the URL and it is working fine.

So the error lies with the Safari browser.

Note that running your Selenium tests on a different browser tends to require additional setup.

You could try manually installing the Safari Driver as described [here](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/69-safari) if it is actually installed.

Comment: Hi Laurentiu, I have tried the code on Firefox and it works fine. When I try the code for Safari, it is launching the Safari browser then crashes immediately.

Comment: @Umasankar Check the safari error logs and update your question. Ex. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4439369